# Concatenate and aggregate json response data with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, concatenation, aggregation

I tried different ways, can anyone explain where am I wrong?

I want to aggregate team members according to their respective teams. I tried this below represented code but, not able to get correct values.
I think I have some problem in variables while fetching values, but I just don't understand the code. Can anyone please explain it ?

Below is my code:  'data' is object returned after a query.

```
      var groups = []
      var Members = []

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

          var team = data[i].UnitId.BlockName;
          var member = { "Name" : data[i].Name, "Mobile" : data[i].Mobile }
          Members.push(member);
          console.log('Members are: '+JSON.stringify(Members));
          //if(data[i].UnitId.BlockName === team){
            var new_obj = { "Team" : team, Members};
            groups.push(new_obj);
          // }
      }

      console.log('Groups: '+JSON.stringify(groups));
      //------------------------------------

      let grouped = {};
      groups.forEach(({Team, Members}) => {
        grouped[Team] = grouped[Team] || {Team, Members: []};
        if (grouped[Team].Members.includes(Members.Name,Members.Mobile))
          grouped[Team].Members.push(Members.Name,Members.Mobile);
        // grouped[id].medal_count = `${(+grouped[id].medal_count)+ (+medal_count)}`;
      });
      grouped = Object.values(grouped);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped));
```

Output:

```
{
    "grouped": [
        {
            "Team": "EasilyDone",
            "Members": []
        },
        {
            "Team": "BrainItOn",
            "Members": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "grouped": [
        {
            "Team": "EasilyDone",
            "Members": 
                     [
                         {
                                "Name" : "Dhairya"
                         }
                     ]
        },
        {
            "Team": "BrainItOn",
            "Members":
                     [
                         {
                                "Name" : "raj"
                         }
                     ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[DATA LOOKS LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIM0T.png)

Comment: Can you post your `data` which you are looping??

Comment: @Subburaj YES! I have attached the link.

Comment: Paste it in question, also don't give image link. If its pasted as text in question means its easy for us to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

```js
let grouped = {};

groups.forEach(({Team, Members}) => {
  grouped[Team] = { Team, Members };
});
```

Also, your code is very convoluted. I suggest you learn how to write Javascript in a neater fashion.

Comment: I am getting null in place of Name. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is this coming from your data array?

Comment: From data I have created a 'groups' json object data.
Now, I wan't to change the format of the 'groups' object.

Comment: Format should be as shown in desired output. I have attached link to my data image, just for reference.